# Can Langlands correpondence be restated using topos?

Tags: ct.category-theory, galois-theory, automorphic-forms, topos-theory, langlands-conjectures

Langlands correspondence describes an equivalence between Galois representations and automorphic representations under some conditions.

Laurent Lafforgue applying Olivia Caramello thesis described in this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/124862/391358) asked a similar question of whether Langland correspondence is a Morita equivalence of classifying topos $\mathcal{E}_{G} \cong \mathcal{E}_{A}$. Topos are sheaves on a Grothendieck site. There is Galois descent described by Keith Conrad [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/galoisdescent.pdf) and automorphic descent described in "The descent map from automorphic representations of $GL(n)$ to
classical groups", World Scientific Press (2011) by D. Ginzburg, S. Rallis, and D. Soudry. Both have descent theories which suggests that there should exist a Galois sheaf on some site and an automorphic sheaf on some site.

1. What would be the Galois topos $\mathcal{E}_{G}$?
2. What would be the automorphic topos $\mathcal{E}_{A}$?

Following this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/286901/391358) and related "An Extension of the Galois theory of Grothendieck" by Joyal and Tierney describes an equivalence between the fundamental group $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ and Galois groups $Gal(L/K)$ using topoi. Following an "Introduction to automorphic representations" by Jayce R. Getz in 15.2 automorphic representations are defined as sheaves of sections $Sh^K$ using a local system and in 15.11 a connection between automorphic representations and Galois representations using a Shimura variety $Sh(G,X)$ is mentioned.

If Galois topoi are the fundamental group $\pi_1(X, x_0)$ and automorphic topoi are local systems, then work has already been done on that problem. See this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/17797/391358) noting that a local system can be derived from a locally constant sheaf. I think this equivalence between the fundamental group and local systems is restating the geometric Langlands correspondence formulated in 3.1 and 3.2 of "Lectures on the Langlands Program and Conformal Field Theory" by Frenkel. That is say this construction using topoi may just be the geometric case.

At least for the Galois side I have some idea of what the topos may be. Groups are examples of topoi. Consider the classical derivation of group cohomology by an (aspherical) Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(\pi_1(X) = G, 1)$ for some group $G$. The Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(G,1)$ is a classifying space $BG$ for the fundamental group $G$. Corollary 1.28 of "Algebraic Topology" by Hatcher provides an explicit construction of a group $G$ being the fundamental group of a 2d cell complex $X_G$  with $G = \pi_1(X_G)$. I think the Galois topos $\mathcal{E}_{G}$ would be $K(G,1)$ for some Galois group $G = Gal(L/K)$.

Comment: In your final sentence, how is the Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(G,1)$ supposed to be a topos? And what is the relevance of Corollary 1.28 of Hatcher?

Comment: @YemonChoi The Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(G,1)$ is a topos because the classifying topos of a group $G$ (its topos) is its classifying space $BG$. Hatcher's Corollary 1.28 is relevant because the fundamental group and their coverings are important when constructing the sheaf of a topos. The sheaf is a presheaf with a covering condition.